# Printing values through pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a class Vertex and a class Graph to draw a graph. I wish to store few vertices i.e. objects of Vertex Class in the Vector of type Vertex, but due to few errors I wasn't able to store the vertex objects directly, so I am storing the references of the objects in vectors. But while displaying I wish to display the vector name on console which I am not able to do so. May be my syntaxes are incorrect. Please help me out. Below is my code for both the classes and main().

My requirement is to display "v1", "v2",... so on, on the console. But right now its only displaying the addresses on the vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, in the first for loop, you're not getting the actual value from "g1.Vertice1[i]" but trying to print the pointer. The type of Vertice1 is `vector<Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>*>` (a vector of pointers to Vertex objects,) so you need to change the line so that it uses the -> operator to dereference the pointer and call of the "Vert" and print the return of that instead of trying to print the pointer's value.

Change

```
std::cout << g1.Vertice1[i]<<endl;
```

to

```
std::cout << g1.Vertice1[i]->Vert() <<endl;
```

Comment: Yes I did try dereferencing it the same way you suggested, but its giving me an error for "<<" in cout saying "No operator '<<' matches these operands"

Comment: Try doing `std::cout << g1.Vertice1[i]->Vert << std::endl;`. I made a mistake by forgetting that the "Vertex" type cannot be printed directly. Editing original too.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you're adding to the `g1.Vertice1` vector:

```
g1.Vertice1.push_back(&v1);
g1.Vertice1.push_back(&v2);
```

The elements of the vector are pointers, not `Vertex` objects.  Which makes sense given that `Vertice1` is declared as a vector of pointers to a specific type of `Vertex`.

When you iterate over the `g1.Vertice1` vector and output its elements you are therefore outputting pointers which is why you are seeing addresses.  So consider dereferencing those pointers in the loop that is trying to print out the vertex names.

Comment: tried dereferencing, but getting error or "<<" in cout saying "No operator '<<' matches these operands"

Comment: That's not surprising -- the `ostream` class can't output arbitrary objects.  Write an overload of `operator<<()` that can produce a decently-printable representation of `Vertex`.  Or add a type conversion that can convert `Vertex` to a `string` or some other thing that `ostream` already knows how to output.